# SSL/TLS configuration with certificate

Tags: spring-security, netty, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-gateway

I encountered a problem with TSL/SSL configuration. Everything is configured like in the documentation https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/multi/multi__tls_ssl.html

```
server:
  port: 8080
  ssl:
    enabled: true
    key-password: password
    key-store-password: password
    key-store: certificate.p12
    key-store-type: PKCS12

spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      httpclient:
        ssl:
          trustedX509Certificates:
            - someCert.pem
```

With this configuration it's impossible to call endpoint with http://localhost:8080/home - and this is a desired behaviour.

Despite the configuration I can call all endpoints like https:localhost:8080/home without applying proper certificate. In chrome I can just click 'proceed anyway' and I get the content of endpoint.

I dont want to allow this - if you want to call endpoint from external world you need to have the client certificate. This is my goal but I am missing something.

How to achieve this using spring cloud gateway?

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is old, but in case anyone else comes across it, you were missing a property:

```
server:
  ssl:
    client-auth: need
```

This will force the server to require a Client Certificate before it will accept connections.